# Обращение к перекрытым совпадающим именем полям

Tags: java, access

Ниже представлен код — работающая программа. Главное здесь: кусок между комментариями `//НАЧАЛО СОЗДАНИЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИИ` и `//КОНЕЦ СОЗДАНИЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИИ`. Понятно, что мы создаём коллекцию с помощью анонимных классов, реализуя абстрактный класс `AbsctractCollection`.

***Вопрос***: как, не прибегая к закомментированию объявления массива `array`, находящегося внутри реализации итератора (место помечено комментарием `// Роковая строка (*)` ), обратиться к массиву `array`: полю внутри самой реализации `AbstractCollection`? Само обращение происходит в строках: `// ЗДЕСЬ (1)`, `// И ЗДЕСЬ (2)`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // НАЧАЛО СОЗДАНИЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИИ
        Collection<Object> coll = new AbstractCollection<Object>() {

            private final int SIZE = 10;
            private Object[] array = new Object[SIZE];

            @Override
            public boolean add(Object o) {
                int i = 0;
                while (i != SIZE && array[i] != null)
                    i++;
                if (i == SIZE)
                    return false;
                array[i] = o;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator<Object> iterator() {

                Object[] array = {10,20,22,33,48,"Hi People",  // Роковая строка (*)
                                 "Кислотный диджей хэй!",
                                 2.0d, 0, null};

                return new Iterator<Object>() {
                    int k = 0;

                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return k != SIZE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object next() {
                        return array[k++];    // ЗДЕСЬ       (1)
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void remove() {
                        if (k == 0)
                            return;
                        array[k - 1] = null;   // И ЗДЕСЬ    (2) 
                    }

                };
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return SIZE;
            }

        };
        // КОНЕЦ СОЗДАНИЯ КОЛЛЕКЦИИ

        for (int i = 34; i < 88; i++)
            coll.add(i);

        coll.remove(40);

        System.out.println(coll);
    }
}


//Output:
//[10, 20, 22, 33, 48, Hi People, Кислотный диджей хэй!, 2.0, 0, null]
```

Эффект, который я хочу достичь, достигается и закомментированием "роковой строки". Результат того же кода, с наложенным комментарием:

```
Output:
[34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, null, 41, 42, 43]
```

---

Псевдокод вопроса:

```
Аноним: {

             Поле P //(1)

             Аноним: { 
                            Поле P   //(2)
                            Вызов(P) // вызывается (2)
             }
        }

// Как вызвать P (1) ?
```

Вот примерно такое решение я хочу получить для моей задачи (представлен пример без анонимных классов):

```
public class Test{

    private String s = "Hello World!";

    public void f(){
        String s = "Strange string";
        class A{
            String s = "You have a small *ick";
            {System.out.println(Test.this.s);}   // Примерно этого хочется.
        }
        new A();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test().f();
    }
}

//Output:
//HelloWorld!
```

***Дополнительно***: а как вызвать `String s = "Strange string";` внутри сегмента `{}` класса `A`?

---

Очень прошу, не надо мне говорить, что можно так, можно сяк, но да обойтись без вызова желаемого поля, или прибегнуть ко всемогущему переименованию. Вопрос очень интересный и сложный. Да, экзотические потребности, но охота разобраться в том, как устроен язык Java.

Если основной или дополнительный вопрос имеют ответ "никак", то просьба объяснить почему, или сослать на какие либо источники информации, где это строго доказано.

Comment: а вы предыдущий похожий вопрос удалили?

Comment: @Direct не стоит "сбрасывать минусы" пересозданием вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее вы можете ссылку на экземпляр внешнего класс получить создав в нём метод, его возвращающий. Это будет заменой варианта получения ссылки на внешний класс по его имени, раз для анонимных классов имени нема.

```
new Outer()
{
    public Outer getOuter()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void outerMethod()
    {
        new Inner()
        {
            public void innerMethod()
            {
                //вот и ссылка на внешний класс. Тут или доступ к переменной будет или можно метод вызвать, который будет массив ваш возвращать. Хотя в этом случае и ссылка, вроде, на внешний класс не нужна...
                getOuter();
            }
        };
    }
};
```

---

В вашем конкретном случае надо как-то так объявить метод во внешнем классе:

```
Collection<Object> coll = new AbstractCollection<Object>() {

    private Object[] array = new Object[SIZE];

    public Object[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

После чего во внутреннем классе вместо обращения к переменной по имени вызывайте метод, её возвращающий.

```
//Вместо
//return array[k++];
return getArray()[k++];
```

---

P.S. Решение придумал сам, а потом (через 3с, после понимания какой запрос в гугл вбить) нашёл откуда код копирнуть, ибо самому лень писать - [How to access “this” reference of anonymous outer class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26400055/3212712)

Comment: А для моего конкретного кода не можете дать решение? Как именно мне обратиться к `array` в реализации `AbstractCollection`? Как именно мне обратиться к строке "Strange string"?

Comment: @Direct, дополнил ответ. Строка или массив - не важно. Для строки делайте аналогично.